# How to export pivot point from Blender to Unreal Engine?

Tags: export

In blender the position of the pivot point is correct.
But it moves to another direction after importing to Unreal.

Why can it be?

I think this is a question more about Unreal, not Blender, but here community helps much more faster, than Unreal community =)

[image]

[image]

**Edit 2:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Before exporting from Blender, add an empty to your scene where you want your origin point to be, then parent the cupboard to the empty.  Optionally rename empty to 'cupboard' or whatever you want.  This works for Unity, and I assume it'd work in UE4.

Comment: I've added empty Plane Axes and made left door of the cupboard a child of that object like in the Edit 1. Is it correct? Pivot points of the both objects are in the same point.

Comment: Not quite what I meant.  In hierarchy view, grab Cube.001 by the icon to the left of it's name and drag it on top of the LeftEmpty.  It should then seem to disappear from the hierarchy view, but if you click the little + beside LeftEmpty, you'll see that it's there as a child of the empty.

Comment: Unfortunately pivot point is still in the wrong place

Comment: If you're exporting "selected objects", be sure to have the empty (parent) selected too, not just the cube.