# Error in exported animation position/size. (Blender to Unreal)

Tags: animation, export, import, unreal-engine

I exported an object and its animations to unreal.

**All right:**

[image]

I have problems when I work with its animations.

**See how the size and base position change:**

[image]

**Skeletal Mesh (apparently all right):**

[image]

**Animation Sequence (see how it looks inside the floor):**

[image]

**In Blender (I put it above the floor):**

[image]

**In Blender (the parent bone is the bone circled in pink):**

[image]

- I think the parent bone is the cause of the position problem, or at least the way I exported the object makes the parent bone influence that aspect.
- About the size, I do not know what is causing the problem because I exported/imported the animation along with the object.

**Questions I looked at before asking my question:**

[Issue with Blender export to Unreal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98059/issue-with-blender-export-to-unreal)

[blender to unreal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122780/blender-to-unreal)

[How to export pivot point from Blender to Unreal Engine?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34367/how-to-export-pivot-point-from-blender-to-unreal-engine)

[Why is my animation being broken up into several files when i export it from blender and import into unreal engine 4?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73905/why-is-my-animation-being-broken-up-into-several-files-when-i-export-it-from-ble)

**A recommended link on one of the questions cited:**

https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/animation/38785-blender-digital-fbx-not-include-all-animations?67714-blender-digital-fbx-not-include-all-animations=

**A setting I use at export time:**

[image]

**The parameters I use are taken from this video:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENqvKrdFbZk&feature=youtu.be

**The link I got by asking this question:**

[Animation is exported, but does not appear along with the mesh of the object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149466/animation-is-exported-but-does-not-appear-along-with-the-mesh-of-the-object)

I would like to know how to make sure that the position (origin) of the object does not change when an animation is played/added/displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**By checking the option circled in pink in the image below, I solved the position and size problem:**

[image]

**Only thing to report is that the parent bone was distorted, as if it had been lengthened:**

[image]

But I didn't notice any difference in the animation.